# Ilog Opl Script mixing mismatch environment error

Tags: ilog, opl

There are 3 models that I run iteratively by using proper outputs. However, at one point, I get “mixing mistach environment” error. The code is basically as below:

```
//model1
..
main{
    generate & solve model1
    call model2
    model1.output_x=model2.input_x
    generate & solve model2
    call model3
    model2.output_y=model3.input_y
    generate & solve model3
}
```

While generating of model 3, mismatch environment error occurs. However, model 2 and model 3 are similar.

At model 3, here’s the constraint that I think causes this problem:

```
totalcost (dvar of model 3)-epsilon(variable of model 3)<=n1_cost (output of model2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be really careful.  The statements

```
model1.output_x=model2.input_x
model2.output_y=model3.input_y
```

seem backwards.  Don't you mean:

```
model2.input_x = model1.output_x
model3.input_y = model2.output_y
```

Having said that, the proper design pattern is to copy the output of one model into ***data*** input for the subsequent model.  If you make sure that you have good model/data separation, then the problem should go away.